# Pandas dataframe, cumsum reset on NAN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know this question exists but I can't find any answer that simple enough to understand and fits my problem. I have a column in a dataframe and I want to keep a running total(cumsum) of this column but resetting on NAN values

```
 Index  s_number  s_cumsum
  0       1         1
  1       4         5
  2       6         11
  3       Nan       0
  4       7         7
  5       2         9
  6       3         12
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `cumsum`:

```
df['s_cumsum'] = df.s_number.groupby(df.s_number.isna().cumsum()).cumsum()
df

   Index  s_number  s_cumsum
0      0       1.0       1.0
1      1       4.0       5.0
2      2       6.0      11.0
3      3       NaN       NaN
4      4       7.0       7.0
5      5       2.0       9.0
6      6       3.0      12.0
```

Note that if "s_number" is a column of strings, use

```
df['s_number'] = pd.to_numeric(df['s_number'], errors='coerce)
```

...first, to get a float column with NaNs.

---

If you want to fill the NaNs,

```
df['s_cumsum'] = (df.s_number.groupby(df.s_number.isna().cumsum())
                    .cumsum()
                    .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))
df

   Index  s_number  s_cumsum
0      0       1.0         1
1      1       4.0         5
2      2       6.0        11
3      3       NaN         0
4      4       7.0         7
5      5       2.0         9
6      6       3.0        12
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if I had 0 or any other character instead of NAN, how would this change in the code

Comment: @Dan change isna() to eq(value).

Answer (score 1):

Turn NaNs into a negative cumsum of previous values, then the cumsum will reset it to 0 at NaNs.

I doubled the df to show how it works.

```
for i in df.loc[np.isnan(df['s_number'])].index:
    df['s_number'] = -sum(df[:i])
df['cumsum'] = df['s_number'].cumsum()

    index  s_number  s_cumsum
0       0       1.0         1
1       1       4.0         5
2       2       6.0        11
3       3     -11.0         0
4       4       7.0         7
5       5       2.0         9
6       6       3.0        12
7       0       1.0        13
8       1       4.0        17
9       2       6.0        23
10      3     -23.0         0
11      4       7.0         7
12      5       2.0         9
13      6       3.0        12
```